# Are there WebView2 equivalents of the CEF DialogHandler and DownloadHandler?

Tags: chromium-embedded, webview2

I'm attempting to convert an app and that uses CEF to use WebView2. The CEF app uses the DialogHandler and the DownloadHandler overrides. I'm trying to find out how to do what these do in WebView2 and I'm not having much luck.

For examples, the app uses the DialogHandler to prepopulate the file selection in a file chooser dialog. The DownloadHandler is more complex. It runs word after the file is downloaded, then uploads the file to another site when the user is done editing and exits word.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: Hello Kevin, for the 2n question I'd say you could handle that with the CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting Event (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.downloadstarting?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49). Not sure about the 1st, maybe CoreWebView2.ScriptDialogOpening Event helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.scriptdialogopening?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49

Comment: Thanks, that's gives me a place to start.

Comment: There's no hook yet for the file selection dialogs. https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/802